# Count the occurrence of a pattern from a column of one file in other file

Tags: file, awk, grep

I created a file with one column with a list of patterns (2,196 in total) that I wanna find in other text file which has approximated 400 millions lines.
For example:

**`file1`**

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
```

**`file2`**

```
abc1
abc1
abc1
abc1
abc1
abc2
abc2
abc2
abc2
```

The desired output:

**file3**

```
abc1    5
abc2    2
```

I can do one by one with awk or grep:

```
awk '/abc1/{++c}END{print c}' file1 | wc -l > file3
```

or

```
grep 'abc1' file1 | wc -l > file3
```

However, when I try:

```
cat file1 | xargs -L 1 grep file2 | wc -l > file3
```

I get an error message:

```
grep: abc1: No such file or directory
grep: abc2: No such file or directory
etc
```

I tried:

```
cat file1 | xargs -L 1 grep '' file2 | wc -l > file3
```

Also does not work! So what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cat file1 | xargs -L 1 grep file2…` is trying to `grep` the pattern `file2` from the non-existing file `abcX`. You could start with something like

```
<file1 xargs -I{} grep "{}" file2
```

and extend this to

```
$ <file1 xargs -I{} sh -c 'printf "%s\t%s\n" "{}" $(grep -c "{}" file2)'
abc1    5
abc2    4
abc3    0
abc4    0
abc5    0
```

but that's not very efficient for a large pattern file.

---

Using `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ grep -F -x -f file1 file2  | sort | uniq -c > file3
```

Output `file3`:

```
      5 abc1
      4 abc2
```

If you need to reverse the number of matches and the pattern:

```
grep -F -x -f file1 file2  | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2"\t"$1 }' > file3
```

Output `file3`:

```
abc1    5
abc2    4
```

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{ a[$0] }
  NR!=FNR && $0 in a{ a[$0]++ }
  END{ for (i in a){ if (a[i])print i"\t"a[i] }}
' file1 file2 > file3
```

Output `file3`:

```
abc1    5
abc2    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution would be as follows IMHO.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next} ($1 in a){print $1,a[$1]}' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file2 is being read.
  a[$0]++                     ##Creating an array named a index is $0 and increment it with 1 each time it goes to line.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){                    ##Checking condition if $1 is present in array a then do following.
  print $1,a[$1]              ##Printing first field then value of array a with index $1.
}
' Input_file2  Input_file1    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
abc1 5
abc2 4
```